# Django Model Objects Bulk Update

Tags: django

I have reset_company_limits module for updating limit of a company, this task is running on daily basis in morning. But somehow some company limit is unable to update. I am not able to find any error in my code

```
def reset_company_limits(comp_id=None, reset_type=['daily', 'monthly']):
    if comp_id:
        company_accounts = CompanyAccount.objects.filter(id=comp_id, enabled=1)
    else:
        company_accounts = CompanyAccount.objects.filter(enabled=1)

    reset, rcache, cache_rec = ({} for l in xrange(3))
    error = []
    for rtype in reset_type:
        for account in company_accounts:
            try:
                counts = account.get_feature_reset_counts(feature_type=reset_type)
                limits = account.get_limits()
                recruiters = account.recruiter_set.filter(is_active=True).values('pk')
                for limit in limits:
                    key = RECRUITER_LOOKUP[limit.type]
                    if key in counts[rtype]:
                        if rtype == 'daily':
                            limit.daily = counts[rtype][key]
                        elif rtype == 'monthly':
                            limit.monthly = counts[rtype][key]
                    limit.save()
            except Exception, e:
                error.append(account.pk)
                print "Error occurred for company id %s :: %s" % (account.pk, e)
    return reset, rcache, cache_rec, error
```

Comment: What does `get_limits` do? What does "unable to update" involve? any errors? What is the "`cache`" supposted to do? as far as I can tell its always an empty dict that you try to delete things from

Comment: get_limits() return model objects (CompanyLimit) assosciated with this company account and no i am not getting any error but still some objects data doesn't seems updated